# Is there a poly time algorithm for finding all approximate zeros contained in $[0,1]$ of a continuous poly computable $f(x)$ with at most m zeros?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Specifically we know that for our function $f$ ($f$ takes real values), $\infty>f(0)>0$, while $-\infty<f(1)<0$. So the classical binary search will find an approximate zero within $\epsilon$ of the actual zero in time $\lceil\log_2(\epsilon^{-1})\rceil$, but what about all the other zeros? Again our algorithm has to be polynomial in $\epsilon^{-1}$ as well.

I guess in general the answer to this question must be 'no'. But if we know that the zeros are bounded away from the endpoints of the interval and each other by some fixed $\epsilon$, then it should be possible. We will then need to take $\delta < \epsilon$ and apply the binary search algorithm recursively to the subintervals marked by each approximate zero.

Does that sound right?

Comment: Is $f$ a computable *real* function or something more conventional?

Comment: Also, suppose that $f(0) = f(1) = 1$. Is it decidable whether $f$ vanishes in $(0,1)$?

Comment: f is polynomially computable rational function $p(x)/q(x)$ where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials with positive integer coefficients and degrees $\leq m$, but we don't know the coefficients. There is just some algorithm for computing the values of the function in time that is polynomial of $m$. So not sure if this information is helpful at all.

Comment: So $f$ accepts a rational number and outputs a rational number? Also, what is your computation model? It seems for you arbitrary-precision arithmetic is for free (i.e., has unit cost).

Comment: I guess, the answer to your question about f(0)=f(1)=1 must be 'no', since it could dip down to $0$ and back up in an arbitrarily small subinterval and in principle, this could happen in my case too, making such an algorithm impossible...

Comment: Not so fast, you do know something about the function $f$. At this point, however, I think you should spend more time on the problem on your own.

Comment: The answer to your second question is that it can accept irrationals, but of course, we are just going to look for rational approximate zeros. As for 'computational model' I am not sure, if that's what you mean, but I am thinking of PTAS.

Comment: No, that's not at all what I meant. In the Turing machine model, a function gets a string as input and returns a string as output. The string can represent whatever you want that has finite description. Irrational numbers in general don't have finite descriptions. One way to get around this is the notion of *real computation*, but I'm not sure that's what you're after. Another option is to have a sort of RAM machine (q.v.) with unit cost exact arithmetic  operations which could result in irrationals, say square root. This is what I meant by "computation model". Where did this question show up?

Comment: We know very little about it except for the values at $0$ and $1$. I also misspoke earlier about $p(x)$ having positive integer coefficients - it would have no zeros on the unit interval in that case.

Comment: Thanks for engaging, Yuval. It showed up in trying to prove that a certain classical quantity in the Ising model is #P-hard by rewriting it as a rational function where the coefficients are known to be #P-hard. It then becomes an interpolation problem - showing that if we can compute the rational function, we can compute the coefficients. It then becomes a linear algebra problem -rewriting it as a linear system and showing that a certain determinant can be made to be non-zero by a choice of points (inputs into the rational function). Anyway... probably too much information...

Comment: By coefficients I mean the coefficients of the polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, where the rational function is $a(x)/b(x)$.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it self-contained and include all relevant information into it.  We shouldn't have to read the comment thread to understand what you are asking.  Comments exist only to help you improve your question.

Comment: The binary search approach won't necessarily find zeroes of even order (i.e. the root $x=0$ of $x^2$).

Comment: Indeed if the zero is also a turning point, that's problematic. But if we rule that out, then it's OK, correct?